# Stream read selected listbox item query

Tags: c#, listbox

I have an app that reads a directory, gets a list of the files (segy) and populates a listbox on the left side of the app with the filenames. Upon clicking an item in the listox I'd like the rich text box on the right to display the content of the file.

I have the app working if I use the openfiledialog to select one of the files in the directory, I'm having issues trying to get the stream reader to read the selected file I've clicked.

The working simple openfiledialog code below.

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
openFileDialog1.Title = "Open SEG-Y Files";
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, ebcdic);
readFile.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
readFile.Read(data, 0, 3200);
string stringData = "";
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    if ((i % 80) == 0 && stringData != "")
        stringData += Environment.NewLine;
        stringData += data[i].ToString();
}
rtbHeader.Text = stringData;
rtb.AppendText(value);
rtb.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
```

My code

```
private void txtUpdate(string value)
    {
        lstFiles.Items.Add(value + Environment.NewLine);
        lstFiles.TopIndex = lstFiles.Items.Count - 1;
        lstFiles.Update();
    }

    private void btnFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPath.Text = "";
        lstFiles.Items.Clear();
        rtbHeader.Clear();
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void btnFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstFiles.Items.Clear();
        string path = txtPath.Text;
        List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtPath.Text, "*.sgy", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Path.GetFileName).OrderBy(x => x));
        if (files == null || files.All(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no files with extension" + " sgy", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => txtUpdate(file)));
        }   
    }

    private void lstFiles_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        rtbHeader.Clear();
        String item = (Convert.ToString(lstFiles.SelectedItem));
        //MessageBox.Show(item);
        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(item, ebcdic);
        readFile.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        readFile.Read(data, 0, 3200);
        string stringData = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 80) == 0 && stringData != "")
                stringData += Environment.NewLine;
            stringData += data[i].ToString();
        }
        rtbHeader.Text = stringData;
    }
}
```

Im getting an Illegal characters in path exception on this bit.

```
StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(item, ebcdic);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you change this statement in the `txtUpdate()` method:

```
lstFiles.Items.Add(value + Environment.NewLine);
```

to this:

```
lstFiles.Items.Add(value);
```

It will work. The exception is most likely caused by the fact that you have newline characters in your strings. Not only does that make the filename not the one you want, it's not a valid character in Windows paths.

Also note that the items in the `ListBox` you've added are already `string`s. You don't need to call `Convert.ToString()` on them. You can just cast them back to a `string`:

```
String item = (string)lstFiles.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, tried your example but got an exception saying it couldn't find the file in my Projects debug folder. I changed your example to String item = (string)txtPath.Text + lstFiles.SelectedItem; this is giving me the right path but there isn't a seperator between the path and the file eg FilePathFile1.sgy so I'm getting a file not found exception.

Comment: Ok got it String item = (string)txtPath.Text + @"\" + lstFiles.SelectedItem; thanks for your help :-)