# Reading 400 byte binary file header in SEGY file

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

In relation to this post [Stream read selected listbox item query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286081/stream-read-selected-listbox-item-query/27286284#27286284)

I am reading a SEGY file (Seismic data) and with the post above I am managing to read the first 3200 bytes which is the Textual File Header of a SEGY file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEG_Y
http://www.seg.org/documents/10161/77915/seg_y_rev1.pdf

What I'd like to do next is read the 400 byte binary file header which comes after the 3200 bytes texual file header.

I've modified my code to try and read the file and skip the first 3200 bytes but it's coming up with an access denied exception which I don't understand why, I can read the texual header fine so I don't think it really is an access issue. I suspect it's how I've set up the binary reading. ( I found the access issue, I wasn't closing the file from the texual header read)

After I've read the binary, I'd like to convert it to readable text and display that in the rich text box, but unfortunately with my limited 5 months of tinkering with C# it's beyond my abilities.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
char[] binary = new char[400];

String item = (string)txtPath.Text + @"\" + lstFiles.SelectedItem;
            FileStream readStream;
            try
            {
                readStream = new FileStream(item, FileMode.Open);
                BinaryReader readBinary = new BinaryReader(readStream);
                readBinary.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                readBinary.Read(binary, 3200, 400);
                string stringData = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    if ((i % 80) == 0 && stringData != "")
                        stringData += Environment.NewLine;
                    stringData += data[i].ToString();
                }
                rtbHeader.Text = stringData + Environment.NewLine;
                rtbHeader.AppendText(item);
                readStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: giving us the exact exception message and which line you're getting it would help.

Answer (score 1):

The `Read` method does not work like that.

You've tried this:

```
readBinary.Read(binary, 3200, 400);
```

This will read the 400 bytes *at the current file pointer* but then start at offset 3200 *in the array*.

This is not what you want according to your description.

Instead, skip the first 3200 bytes manually, then specify 0 for that parameter:

```
readStream = new FileStream(item, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader readBinary = new BinaryReader(readStream);
readBinary.BaseStream.Seek(3200, SeekOrigin.Begin);
readBinary.Read(binary, 0, 400);
```

From the [documentation of BinaryReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143295(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **index**
>   The starting point in the buffer at which to begin reading into the buffer.

Comment: Hi @LasseeVKarlsen Thanks for responding, I tried your example but the only output I'm getting is the file name from this line rtbHeader.AppendText(item); from String item = (string)txtPath.Text + @"\" + lstFiles.SelectedItem; I'd assume I should get unreadable text in my RTB? Which leads me to another question (I've ameneded my post) how would I convert my code to read the binary and display it in human readable form? I found this page on the web http://www.dotnetperls.com/binaryreader under the heading encoding it shows an example of reading binary with ASCII encoding but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did my answer work, did it read 400 bytes from position 3200, or not?

Comment: Hi Lassee, I got no output, not saying there is anything wrong with your suggestion but I can't get it to work. I'll continue to play with it.

Comment: Anyone else able to give some advice as to why I get no output from the above correction to my code from Lassee?

Comment: Perhaps the file is not 3200 bytes in size?

Comment: Hi Lasse, no the file is not 3200 bytes in size, the text header is, then comes 400 bytes of binary then 240 bytes trace headers. I can read the 3200 bytes perfectly just not the binary. Some of these files are GB's in size but I'm only interested in reading the start of them.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help. "Get no output" is not very much I can go on, you're going to have to debug your code more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read carefully the definition of the 400-byte Binary File Header record: They are defined as two-byte or four-byte, two's complement integers. such as 3201-3204,this is four-byte, 3213-3214,this is two-byte. Other than that, the segy file is a IBM's big-endian data. I think you need to convert big-endian to little-endian on windows operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a real programmer, I was messing around with c# and wrote the following code to read the binary header of a SEGY file, I hope this can give you some hints:

```
namespace SEGY_TEST
{
    class BinaryHeader
    {
        string fname;
        public int si;
        public int spt;
        public int fc;
        public string sfc;
        public int bytef; // byte format.
    public BinaryH(string fname)
    {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lee();
        this.segyformat(this.fc);


        //Console.WriteLine("Abriendo {0}", this.fname);
    }


    public void segyformat(int fc)
    {
        switch (this.fc)
        {
            case 1:
                this.bytef = 4;
                this.sfc= "IBM-FLOAT";
                break;
            case 3:
                this.bytef = 2;
                this.sfc = "INT-16";
                break;

            case 5:
                this.bytef = 4;
                this.sfc = "IEEE-FLOAT";
                break;
            case 8:
                this.bytef = 1;
                this.sfc = "INT-8";
                break;

            default:

                while (true) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} -- FORMAT NOT SUPPORTED PLEASE EXIT",this.fc);
                    Console.Read();
                } 


        }
    }

    public void lee()
    {
        byte[] datos=new byte[400];
        using (FileStream readFile = new FileStream(this.fname,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            readFile.Seek(3200, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            readFile.Read(datos, 0, 400);
            readFile.Close();
        }

        this.si = Endiann.BE16ToInt16(datos, 16); // sample interval
        this.spt = Endiann.BE16ToInt16(datos, 20); // samples per trace
        this.fc = Endiann.BE16ToInt16(datos, 24); // format code

        //Console.WriteLine("{0} sample interval",si);
        //Console.WriteLine("{0} sample per trace", spt);
        //Console.WriteLine("{0} Fomrmat code", fc);

    }
}
}

    public static int BE16ToInt16(byte[] buf, int i)
    {
        return (Int16)((buf[i] << 8) | buf[i + 1]);
    }
```